# Bootstrap collapsed navbar toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The toggle button appears when window is resized small enough but when pressed the button does nothing. I checked over the html several times and made sure the bootstrap files uploaded properly but still to no avail.

Also is there a way to change the parent breakpoint for the toggle button to appear as navbar links squash up relatively quickly as they are so large.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  font-family: 'brandon grotesque'
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid white 2px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
  margin-top: 23px;
  padding: 9px 10px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
    padding-top: 26.5px;
    padding-bottom: 26.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>MASSERIA ELYSIUM</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/psn0aff.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"></div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DINING</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ACCOMODATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <a class="button" href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Am pretty new to coding html so please help me :)

Comment: It definitely works, you see a small jerk. It's just `overflow: hidden`

Comment: You are loading a `main.css` file, what is it exactly?

Comment: You are targeting `#myNavbar` which is an empty div and is not wrapping anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `navbar-collapse` twice, the main one being an empty `<div>`. Replace the following:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"></div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

With the following:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
```

Remove once and you get this working:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  font-family: 'brandon grotesque'
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid white 2px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-in;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
  margin-top: 23px;
  padding: 9px 10px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
    padding-top: 26.5px;
    padding-bottom: 26.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: static;
    color: #fff;
    transform: none;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>MASSERIA ELYSIUM</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/psn0aff.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DINING</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ACCOMODATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <a class="button" href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

For your second issue:

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Remove this in the media query for smaller devices and remove the transform too.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: static;
    transform: none;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]